# Pronunciation of “tour”

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, dialects, vowels, rhoticity

Is the following pronunciation of the word “tour” attested in any common dialect of British English?

- [tɔ˞]

This is approximately how I, a native British English speaker, pronounce it. However, it’s been described by a non-native speaker as “unintelligible”.

The dictionary pronunciation is [tʊər], which — if you ignore my non-rhotic accent — is *pretty* close to mine. So close, I find it hard to believe it’s unintelligible; I can barely hear the difference. There is an allophone and near-allophone in my idiolect -- "tor" ([tɔ˞]) and "taw" ([tɔ]) -- but these are very niche words (I can safely say I've never heard or used the latter!)

---

[The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/TOUR) gives two pronunciations for *tour*. The American Heritage entry, using its own transcription gives:  (to͝or). This vowel is the same vowel as in the word *book*. I'm sure I've never heard that! The other entry for British English, by Collins Dictionary  gives /tʊə/. However, it's well known that dictionary's often don't give alternative standard pronunciations, or regional ones and often use out of date ones too.

Comment: I don't have anything like [Jonathon Woss's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Ross) "speech impediment", but my speech is completely non-rhotic, and I'm totally incapable of rolling my r's. But 50 years ago in my first university linguistics lecture it became apparent that I have a smaller set of "significant phonemes" than most of my compatriots. Unless I make a real effort to enunciate in a way that feels unnatural to me, my ***four, fool, fall, full*** are all pretty much indistinguishable without context.

Comment: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tour) gives audio pronunciations for UK and US dialects. We can't hear how you say it.

Comment: The OED gives  Brit. /tʊə/, /tɔː/, U.S. /tʊ(ə)r/

Comment: @Greybeard FYI, that /tʊ(ə)r/ isn’t so great a representation of even the rhotic American pronunciations of *tour*; see my comment to Araucaria’s answer. Our rhotic speakers with the Mᴀʀʏ-ᴍᴀʀʀʏ-ᴍᴇʀʀʏ merger neutralize all lax–tense distinctions before phonemic R in the coda—and may smooth diphthongs into monophthongs—leaving *tour* with tense vowels like [tʰuɹ], [tʰuwɚ], [tʰoɻ] for most of us, with diverse narrower transcriptions also possible. [¹](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects)⸴ [²](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diphthong#English)

Comment: "The American Heritage entry, using its own transcription gives: (to͝or). This vowel is the same vowel as in the word book." It's certainly not the vowel that "book" has in Standard AmE.

Comment: The dictionary pronunciation is a diphthong:  /tʊə/ or /tuə/. This is ***not*** close to a monophthong unless you are a native English speaker whose ears have been acclimated to the English language.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/599686/2085).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

John Wells, in his interesting and very readable paper [*Whatever happened to Received Pronunciation?*](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/rphappened.htm) makes the following observations about what is known as the CURE vowel, the diphthong /ʊə/, which a small number of speakers in the UK use for the word *tour*:

> **Decline and disappearance of /ʊə/**. Words formerly containing the diphthong /ʊə/ have come increasingly to be pronounced with /ɔː/ instead. Thus *your* is no longer /jʊə/ but /jɔː/. *Poor, sure, moor, cure, tourist* are often /pɔː, ʃɔː, mɔː, kjɔː, ˈtɔːrɪst/. My survey figures for *poor* showed that when we group all ages together /pɔː/ was preferred over the traditional /pʊə/ by a margin of 57% to 43% of the respondents; but when we look at different age-groups separately /pɔː/ was preferred by only 27% of the oldest respondents (born before 1923) as against a massive 81% of the youngest (born since 1962). Words such as *jury*, *rural* seem generally to be resistant to this change, and do not rhyme with *story*, *choral*. Rather, they seem now typically to be pronounced with a monophthong of the [ʊː] type, perhaps to be interpreted as a variant of /uː/.

We can see there that the old CURE vowel, /ʊə/, has become virtually obsolete in the UK, certainly amongst RP speakers and has been replaced by /ɔ:/. The dictionaries seem to be a bit reticent about recognising this or giving /ɔ:/ as the predominant pronunciation. The Original Poster, however, specifically asks about /tɔ˞/ for the word *tour*, with an r-coloured vowel This is  a rhoticised version of the modern RP one, and it would be surprising if there weren't  some rhotic speakers in the UK who used it.

Comment: The vowel in North American rhotic pronunciations of *tour* notably varies from east to west. In the Northeast it **can** be the one you describe in /tɔ˞/, but any further west and it’s ***much*** more apt to be the ɢᴏᴏꜱᴇ vowel than the ᴛʜᴏᴜɢʜᴛ vowel or the ɢᴏᴀᴛ vowel. Whether you write that as [tʰuɹ], [tʰuwɚ], [tʰʊwɚ] may depend on just which features you’re trying to illustrate. The tense–lax distinction is neutralized before phonemic R here for nearly all of us: we hear any such vowel as tense/close. Having the ᴛʜᴏᴜɢʜᴛ vowel there is a Northeastern oddity to the rest of us.

Comment: For my two cents (midwest), "tour" is decidedly a two-syllable word containing the GOOSE vowel. It doesn't rhyme with "four" or "poor" but basically rhymes with "fewer".

Comment: The OP says they have a non-rhotic accent.

Comment: @tchrist: Are you saying that pronouncing "tour" to rhyme with "more" is uncommon in the US outside the Northeast?  In my own personal experience it seems quite common.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, with the vowel of *tour* being the same as in *tourist* and *touring*. All three of those have the  /u/ of *two*, not the /o/ of *toe*.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oops. I misread that! Thanks.